# Check if one cell is contained in a group of cells [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets document that looks like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
1
2   X   X   3
3   Z   Y   2
4       Z
5
```

How can I sum the values in column C if their corresponding values in column A are in column B?
In this case, it would be 3 + 2 because both X and Y are in column B.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you mean "both X and Z are in column B" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C,COUNTIF(B2:B,A2:A)))
```

#### Docs

- [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)
- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)